# AS3 manipulating motion tweens by code

Tags: actionscript-3, tween, motion

This isn't a problem question, its a noob question.

So I need to activate animations on demand using as3, here's the setup I have:

[image]

So I don't know how I can manipulate each tween, I'm using .stop to make everything stop but how can I play only one of those tweens?

Also to note is that those are all inside of a MovieClip object.

I know this is a biginer question but I tried a lot of ways to do it and I can't seem to trigger the animation by name. if I use `rollLeft.play();` it doesn't recognize the rollLeft.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put each one of those tweens into its own MovieClip. So your main timeline will only have one frame with those four MovieClips.

To address each individual MovieClip, you need to give them instance names (select the clip on the stage and give it an instance name in the Properties panel).

Then you can do `rollLeft.stop();`, or `backFlip,play();`, or `rollRight.gotoAndPlay(5);`, etc.

Comment: ok thanks. I tout I could get away without those extra MovieClips